# Naming convention for methods returning RxJava's Completable

Tags: android, rx-java, naming-conventions, naming, reactive

I have and Android app with the view class (`Fragment`, `Activity`) observing its `ViewModel`.

The `ViewModel` exposes methods such as `getUserName` which returns `Observable<String>`. Although maybe there is a possibility to find a better name (maybe `observeUserName`), I'm happy with the current one - it is quite explanatory.

However, here starts the hard part: `ViewModel` also can tell the view to perform some operation - for example close itself, pop backstack etc. For this case `ViewModel` defines following method (and corresponging `Subject`):

```
class ViewModel {
   // other methods, fields

   // ViewModel can call returnToPreviousScreen.onComplete()
   CompletableSubject returnToPreviousScreen = CompletableSubject.create();

   Completable returnToPreviousScreen() { return returnToPreviousScreen; }
}
```

In my opinion, the method's name is terrible. Hovewer I can not find anything better. Something like `observeWhenToReturnToPreviousScreen` is maybe more explanatory but hard to read.

So, are there any recommendations or maybe commonly used practices for naming such methods?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*There's no universal answer to the naming problem, so the only thing you can get are **opinions**.*

---

## Rule of thumb

My approach to naming in rx-java usually looks at two things:

1. Does it express a "stream" of emitted events (**usually** with a plural form of a noun)?
2. Does it work well with other parts of rx java methods chain, and especially the `subscribe` method?

Both of the above can be usually simplified to trying to put the name of the method in this sentence:

> This code **subscribes** to `{name_of_the_method}`.

---

## Examples

A) `getUserName`

> This code **subscribes** to `getUserName`.

The sentence does **not** really make sense because `getUserName` does not express the `stream`. Quite on the contrary, it suggests that there is one value that you can `get`.

```
getUserName().subscribe()
```

---

B) `observeUserName`

> This code **subscribes** to `observeUserName`.

Although the method kind-of expresses the `stream` of events, it does not work well with `subscribe`. Method exposing the `Observable` is not a place for information about `observing`. The consumer of the method will be observing what that method returns.

```
observeUserName().subscribe()
```

---

C) `userNames`

> This code **subscribes** to `userNames`.

This might work in some cases. It nicely expresses a stream of `userName` items being emitted and works well with `subscribe`. It really depends on a particular scenario, because it suggests that you can expect multiple `userNames` while you really want to observe how a single `userName` changes.

```
userNames().subscribe()
```

---

C) `userNameChanges`

> This code **subscribes** to `userNameChanges`.

This method nicely expresses that there is a stream of items ("change" events) and it works well with `subscribe` method.

```
userNameChanges().subscribe()
```

---

#### Return to previous screen

As far as your `returnToPreviousScreen` case goes, I think I would end up using something like:

> This code **subscribes** to `returnRequests()`.

or

> This code **subscribes** to `previousScreenRequests()`.

or even a singular form as there can only be one event emitted in the stream:

> This code **subscribes** to `previousScreenRequest()`.

(*not a topic of a question but I think I would use a `Single<Unit>` rather than `Completable`, to express a singular event emission rather than a completion... but maybe that's just me*).